# Create Edit Item button

Tags: 2010, edit-form, dispform

Using SharePoint 2010, I need to hide the ribbon on a dispform (which I know how to do) but want to make an Edit Item button available in a webpart to a certain audience. So far all I have been able to find is that I can hyperlink the URL with `.../editform.aspx?ID={@ID}` but that does not work. It opens the edit form, but not for that specific ID.

I also tried to hyperlink the URL with `.../editform.aspx?ID={$Rows/@ID}` and that did not work.

Comment: Are you looking for a button for each item?

Comment: I want to apply it to the display form. Then when clicked, it would open that item's edit form.

Comment: Do you have access to SharePoint Designer? If so, you could create a workflow that runs on creation of an item. Have it populate a multiple lines of text field with the URL, and you can insert `current item ID`. Another option would be a calculated column, using the `Concatenate` function.

Comment: I would like to avoid using workflows. I believe there is a way to capture the ID and doing it programmatically.

Comment: Have you tried using a calculated column?

Comment: I need to do it as a webpart and not as a calculated column so that I can make it visible to only a certain audience.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much sure about target audience you have to check it out.
But if your problem exist then you can try creating new page with DataViewWebPart that will display items as per your current DisplayForm and in DVWP there are options to EDIT and DELETE items.

just a work around you have to give a try.